# Members only based plugin for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone recommend me a good members-only plugin?  I want to hide pages (and their tabs) if users aren't signed in.

So far I have found:

- 'Member Access' which doesn't hide the tabs
- 'wp-members' which wouldn't work with 2.8.4
- 'user access manager' which was too complex clunky to be useful.

There should be something basic out there for what I need, but no luck so far.

Comment: What do u mean by hiding tabs? Is it the menu links?

Comment: I want to hide the menu links to pages that users would not have access to.  I am using this theme:
http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/inove

Comment: Then I would recommend you try out Littlejon's plugin. OR use "Member Access" plugin AND hack some PHPs to hide the tabs.

Comment: do you just want to hide the links from menu or you actually want users to not even see the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Justin Tadlock](http://justintadlock.com/) is a WordPress heavy (wrote the popular [Hybrid](http://themehybrid.com/themes/hybrid) theme framework), recently released a comprehensive user management plugin called [Members](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/17/members-wordpress-plugin), which among other things can turn your blog into a login-only venue:

> Private Blog: Allows you to create a
>   private blog that can only be accessed
>   by users that are logged in (redirects
>   them to the login page).

But I get the impression that you're looking to keep some part available to the public users and other parts only for registered users.

You can also use this plugin to restrict certain areas of your blog, screenshot example here: [based on role](http://justintadlock.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/content-permissions.png)

Hiding the tabs from the public user is the challenging part. Themes typically aren't designed with private portions in mind; you'd have to hack it yourself or get someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If are familiar with php and WP structure, you can add a few lines of code to a few template files to redirect users to login page if they are not signed-in. Let me know if you want to go that way. I can try to provide sample code. Are you using one of the basic themes?

Comment: I'm new to Wordpress and I wasn't sure if the best way was to modify the template files, but I guess that's my best option.  Use the 'Member Access' plugin that disables access, and then modify the theme to hide the main links.  I'm a C# developer so I have the background to figure out the PHP.

A bit of background is I had a phpNuke site, but everytime I modified code it made it a huge chore if I ever wanted to upgrade.  Thats why I was trying to stay away from this.

Comment: @Scott: Worpress has a pretty need framework underneath, and PHP should be a piece of cake for you. Here's a documentation for you to check if the user is logged into WP. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

Comment: I wrote my theme a number of years ago, and upgraded my WP instance many times over that period. Nothing has ever broken because the underlying method for exposing content to the theme has been pretty stable.

Answer (score 0):

I have a plugin called "LJ Custom Menu Links" that can do what you are asking. However as the name suggests they are custom links, so you would have to hand add the pages you want. But it does/and can only show a link when a user is logged on if that is what you want. Combined with "pagemash" plugin which will hide pages from the menu generated by WP itself leaving only the pages linked to by the LJ Custom Menu Links plugin.

However I was under the impression if you made a Page private then it wouldn't show up unless someone was logged in, or am I wrong on that one?

Answer (score 0):

A good option is to use three difference plugins:

Member Access
Register Plus
AJAX Login Widget++

You can find my post on all these here:

http://sbhosting.com/wordpress-member-area/

Answer (score 0):

[A paid option is this](http://member.wishlistproducts.com/?af=955679). It's VERY good.  I use it on several websites.  Called Wishlist Memeber

Comment: If you need to do any sort of custom development, Wishlist member is a bad choice.  The whole plugin is encrypted, and the vast majority of the membership info (which you might need to use other places - like to integrate with bbpress) is stored in a single option variable, making it super clunky to deal with.  Given a second chance, I'd steer clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try [CMS Members](http://wpwave.com/plugins/cms-members/)

I know it hide some pages for non-members.

Answer (score 0):

For me [s2member](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/s2member/)  does the job. You don't have to use the paypal option, you can stick with free membership.